# React-native-pin-input can't remove between space-cells

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I'm using react-native-pin input to take input. spacing between pin labels is very large. I can't able to increase or decrease it.

```
  <PinInput
    style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'stretch'}}
    ref={(input) => {
        this.pin = input;
    }}
    text=""
    pinLength={4}
    pinItemStyle={{width: 50, height: 50, borderTopWidth: 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 2, borderColor: 'green'}}
    pinItemProps={{keyboardType: 'number-pad', returnKeyType: 'done', secureTextEntry: false}}
    placeholder={'_'}
    onPinCompleted={(pin) => {
        this.setState({pin: pin});
        Keyboard.dismiss();
    }}
    onPinKeyPress={(e, i) => {
        let message = `i:${i},key:${e.nativeEvent.key}`;
        console.log(message)
        this.setState({log: this.state.log + message})
    }}
    containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
    containerPinStyle={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
    }}
  />
```

let me know how to reduce space.

Answer (score 0):

Change your style attribute "justifyContent" to this:

```
style={{justifyContent: 'space-between', alignSelf: 'stretch'}}
```

This will reduce the space between the pins. Let me know if this works for you!